# Android Virtual Devise not working

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm new to Android software development. to install the virtrual devise on Eclipse, I followed the steps as mentioned on http://developer.android.com/ but when I launch it, it starts loading and stops there! 
! it just shows me the word "android" glinting. So what should I do to make it work?

[image: AVD not working]

[Sorry for my bad english.]

Comment: "What should I do to make it work?" wait longer...the emulator is very slow

Answer (score 0):

The emulator is quite slow. If you see the Android logo, then it is booting. You just need to wait it out.

If you have an Intel processor on your development machine and are running Windows or Mac, I suggest that install HAXM and configure your emulator to use an Intel image. You will see a significant speed boost. For details, see [this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture).

Comment: Thank you Bro. I will check the link